# Probability that the difference of the max and min of three random numbers between 0 and 2 is less than 1/4?

Tags: probability

Three numbers are chosen at random between 0 and 2. What is the probability that the difference between the largest number and the least number is less than 1/4?

This is a problem from JHMT Calculus 2011. I'm trying to see if there are any better solutions than the one provided.

Here is the solution provided:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the solution provided ?

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: the provided solution looks pretty sweet

Comment: Topic reference : Problems like this can be solved with the methods of Order Statistics, which can be found in a good university-level introductory statistics text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically along the same lines as provided answer.

First note that the answer won't change if we assume $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are IID $\mbox{U}[0,1]$, and we're asking what is the probability that the difference between the maximum and the minimum is at most $\frac 18$.

More generally, suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are IID $\mbox{U}[0,1]$, and we're asked for the probability that the difference between the maximum and minimum is at most $\alpha$.  The answer then is

$$ n  \times \int_0^1 P( \bigcap_{j=2}^n  \{t<X_j < t+\alpha\}|X_1=t) dt =  n \times \int_0^1 \min (\alpha,1-t)^{n-1} dt.$$

The expression on the right is

$$ n \times \left (  \alpha^{n-1}\times (1-\alpha) +  \int_0^\alpha u^{n-1} du\right)=n \alpha^{n-1} (1-\alpha) + \alpha^n = n \alpha^{n-1} -(n-1) \alpha^n. $$

In the case $n=3$ and $\alpha=\frac 18$, this formula gives $\frac{11}{256}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given:  parent random variable $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,2)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

**Order Statistics**

A more general framework for solving such problems is to use order statistics. In particular, given a random sample of size $n$ drawn on parent $X$, the joint pdf of the sample minimum (the $1^{\text{st}}$ order statistic) and sample maximum (the $n^{\text{th}}$ order statistic), say $g(x_1, x_n)$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the mechanics. We could just as easily find the joint pdf of the $2^{\text{nd}}$ and $n^{\text{th}}$ order statistics in the same way, or indeed any combination of 3 or more such ordered variables.

In this instance, we seek $P(X_n - X_1 < \frac14)$:

[image]

When the sample size $n = 3$, this is equal to $\frac{11}{256}$.

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` function used above is also from *mathStatica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.